# HTML table, edit records individually

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, jsp, jstl

I have an HTML table which is filled with database information:

```
    <sql:setDataSource
        var="myDS"
        driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/base_final"
        user="root" password="Valeria"
    />

    <sql:query var="listaTrabajadores" dataSource="${myDS}">
        SELECT * FROM trabajador;
    </sql:query>

    <div class="well form-horizontal">
        <table class="table table-responsive">
            <label class="control-label">Lista de trabajadores</label>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Tipo de trabajador</th>
                <th>Nombre de Usuario</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach var="trabajador" items="${listaTrabajadores.rows}">
                <tr class="table-row"data-href="http://tutorialsplane.com">
                    <td style="cursor: pointer; color: blue;"><c:out value="${trabajador.id_trabajador}" /></td>
                    <td style="cursor: pointer; color: blue;"><c:out value="${trabajador.nombre}" /></td>
                    <td style="cursor: pointer; color: blue;"><c:out value="${trabajador.tipo_trabajador}" /></td>
                    <td style="cursor: pointer; color: blue;"><c:out value="${trabajador.usuario}" /></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Now, what I want is: when clicking a row it will redirect to another page to edit that record.

My question is basically how can I pass the ID of the "trabajador" to another page using JSP/Servlets?

Also, how can the JSP differentiate between all the

> "${trabajador.id_trabajador}"

I mean, how can different values be identified by the same value name?

So, I want to assume I need a Javascript function that calls a Get method, I already have a function that makes the rows clickable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".table-row").click(function() {
        window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
    });
});
</script>
```

Editing the record itself isn't an issue, I already have the necessary code to do that, again, I just need to pass that ID to the controller.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best option to pass id, is to add new column with edit link

```
    <tr class="table-row"data-href="http://tutorialsplane.com">
    <td style="cursor: pointer; color: blue;"><c:out value="${trabajador.id_trabajador}" /></td>
    .........whatever..........
    <td ><a class="tbl-row-edit" data-id="put unique id here">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
```

Then in jquery,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".tbl-row-edit").click(function() {
        window.location.href = "http://domain/edit.jsp?unique_id="+$(this).attr("data-id");
    });
});
</script>
```